# Prove that $\{a_n\} ^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to $A$ if and only if $\{a_n − A\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to zero.

Tags: real-analysis

Here is my rough draft of the proof.My proof seems trivial however, I'm not too confident in it as I don't know how to algebraically explain subtraction of zero in the inequality

Proof:

Forward proof

let $\{a_n\} ^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converge to $A$ , thus by definition of convergence to a limit $$|a_n -A|< \epsilon$$ therefore $$|(a_n -A)-0|< \epsilon$$

thus by definition of of convergence to a limit, $\{(a_n-A)\} ^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to $0$.

Backward proof

let $\{a_n\} ^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converge to $0$ thus by definition of convergence to a limit $$|(a_n -A)-0|< \epsilon$$ therefore $$|a_n -A|< \epsilon$$

thus by definition of of convergence to a limit, $\{a_n\} ^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to $A$.

thus we have proved the statement.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: You've certainly got the right idea, but you can (and should) express it a little more precisely.  What you need to do (in both directions) is choose an arbitrary $\epsilon \gt 0,$ and then prove $\exists N$ such that $\forall n \gt N$ the appropriate difference is less than $\epsilon$.  In each case the same $N$ works for both directions of the implication, but you need to introduce that concept.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "$|a_n - A| < \varepsilon$"

- What is epsilon?  It has not been introduced.  Could $\varepsilon$ be $-1$?
- Are there constraints on $n$ or is this inequality true for all $n \in [1,\infty)$?

The same comments apply to the reverse direction.